# Copy and alter strategy on a table

Tags: postgresql, data-migration

We have a postgresql table where we just recently found out that in our of our tables (table name = orders) in production, one of the column would need to change its type from Integer to Bigint. We can't do this directly in the production table so the plan is....

The plan is:

1. Create a new table with the same specs as the old table. (orders_temp)
2. Create the needed indexes and triggers for the new table
3. Change the data type of that particular column from integer to BigInt
4. Run a data copy job to copy data from old table to new (including replication when data migration is done)
5. Switch table names:
   rename orders_temp to orders
   rename orders to orders_backup

Would this process have any complications?

Comment: There are a couple of things to be taken care. 
Copying data can take really a significant amount of time and since this is your production DB, this can lead to potential downtime or reduced application performance during the migration process. And if any new data is written to the original table during migration, it can also lead to data inconsistencies between the old and new tables. You should temporarily lock the original table or do something else to prevent future writes.

Comment: And, I'm just curious to understand the kind of problems that you will face when you directly modify the column type in the production table. I know it carries the risk of data loss or corruption. Can you also please write why you can't do this directly in the production table.

Comment: `I know it carries the risk of data loss or corruption` @BeulahEvanjalin does it? Why do you think that?

Comment: It is unclear how you intend to pull this off without down time. Loading data is much faster if you create the indexes afterwards.

Comment: "*Would this process have any complications?*" - if you run the copy job and the renaming separately, not inside a transaction, there's a chance it will miss some data that was inserted after the copying and before the rename.